# Error c programming signal

Tags: c, signals

Hello i have problem on my c program, i don't understand because gcc print this error:

```
**ERRROR:**
    counter.c:31:7: error: no member named 'sa_handle' in 'struct sigaction'
       sa.sa_handle=sighandlerUSR1;
       ~~ ^
    counter.c:31:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sighandlerUSR1'
       sa.sa_handle=sighandlerUSR1;
                    ^
    counter.c:80:4: error: expected identifier or '('
       return 0;
       ^
    counter.c:81:1: error: extraneous closing brace ('}')
    }

^


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv){

   int nf=atoi(argv[1]);
   int nsec=atoi(argv[2]);
   struct sigaction sa;
   int globalcount=0,status,atteso;



   if(argc<2){

    printf("\n Errore: il numero di argomenti deve essere 2 \n ");

    exit(-1);

   }


   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

    sa.sa_flags=0;

   //setto handle il gestore

   sa.sa_handle=sighandlerUSR1;


   int pid;

   //codice figlio

 if((pid=fork())==0){

   printf("\n \n PID(FIGLIO): %d \n ",getpid());
   while(globalcount<nf){

       sleep(1);
       globalcount++;

    }   

 }

  //codice padre

   else{

    printf("\n \n PID(PADRE): %d \n ",getpid());

    //il processo padre attende la morte dei figli
     sleep(nsec);

     if(sigaction(SIGUSR1,&sa,NULL)<0){

       perror("Sigaction: ");

       exit(5);
      }

    else{

      printf("\n Sigusr1 lanciato con successo dal padre \n");
    }

     wait(&status);     
   }

   printf("\n GlobalCount: %d \n \n ",globalcount);



   }      

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Then you will probably find the problem yourself. There is one excess `} ` somewhere.

Comment: Well, (1) it's called `sa_handler`, not `sa_handle`, (2) there is no `sighandlerUSR1` to be seen, and (3) you do have an extra `}` before `return 0`.  Not mentioned in the error messages: you're also missing two `#include`s for `wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo, it should be `sa.sa_handler`

Answer (score 0):

The struct member is `sa_handler`, with an 'r' at the end, not `sa_handle`.

Once you've corrected that, you'll need to remove the extraneous `}` before the `return 0;` line, and implement `sighandlerUSR1`...